# Why does the compiling produces `Undefined control sequence` error?

Tags: pdftex, texmaker

Here is the code I have written. There is nothing defined at line 43 but still I get the error:

`Undefined control sequence` for line 43. Anyone has any idea why is this happening ?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

\usepackage[LGR]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek]{babel}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {figures/} }
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                chains,
                positioning,
                quotes}

\begin{document}    
\begin{titlepage}

   \begin{center}
       \vspace*{1cm}
       \huge
       \textbf{Μοντελοποίηση και Αυτόματος Έλεγχος Μηχανικού Συστήματος}

       \vspace{0.5cm}
       \large
        \textbf{Εφαρμογή θεωρίας αναγνώρισης συστήματος και αυτόματου ελέγχου στο μηχανικό σύστημα:}
        \newline
        \newline 
        \textbf{Ράβδος - Μπάλα}

        \vspace{1.5cm}
        \large
        \textbf{Πρωτούλης Θεόδωρος}

        \href{mailto:theoprotoulis@gmail.com}{\latintext{theoprotoulis@gmail.com}}

        \vspace{1cm}

        \begin{center}
        Αριστοτέλειο Πανεπιστημίο Θεσσαλονίκης
        \end{center}

        \begin{center}
        Μάρτιος 2020
        \end{center}

   \end{center}
\end{titlepage}
    \tableofcontents

    \listoffigures  
    \begin{figure}
%   \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-     image}
    %\caption{Test}
    \end{figure}

    \chapter{Εισαγωγή}

    \section{Περιγραφή}

    \chapter{Μοντελοποίηση}

    \section{\latintext{Lagrangian Mechanics}}

    \section{\latintext{Newton's Law of Physics}}

    \section{Γραμμικοποίηση}

    \chapter{Αναγνώριση Συστήματος}

    \section{Συλλογή Δεδομένων Εισόδου - Εξόδου}

    \section{Προεπεξεργασία Δεδομένων}  

    \textbf{Εδώ θα μιλήσουμε για την προεπεξεργασία των δεδομένων}  

    \section{Γραμμική Παραμετροποίηση}

    \section{Μέθοδος των Ελαχίστων Τετραγώνων}

    \chapter{Αξιολόγηση Μοντέλου}

    \section{Συλλογή Δεδομένων Αξιολόγησης}

    \chapter{Ελεγκτής \latintext{PID}}

    \section{Περιγραφή Δομής Ελεγκτή}

    \section{Μαθηματική Ανάλυση}

    \section{Προσομοίωση}

    \section{Εφαρμογή στο Πραγματικό Σύστημα}

    \section{Σχολιασμός Αποτελεσμάτων}  

    \chapter{Ελεγκτής Πλήρους Ανάδρασης Καταστάσεων}

    \section{Περιγραφή Δομής Ελεγκτή}

    \section{Μαθηματική Ανάλυση}

    \section{Σχεδίαση Παρατηρητή}

    \section{Προσομοίωση}

    \section{Εφαρμογή στο Πραγματικό Σύστημα}

    \section{Σχόλιασμός Απόδοσης}   

    \chapter{Ελεγκτής Δυναμικής Ανάδρασης Καταστάσεων}

    \section{Περιγραφή Δομής Ελεγτκή}

    \section{Μαθηματική Ανάλυση}

    \section{Σχεδίαση Παρατηρητή}

    \section{Προσομοίωση}

    \section{Εφαρμογή στο Πραγματικό Σύστημα}

    \section{Σχολιασμός Απόδοσης}

    \chapter{Γραμμικός Τετραγωνικός Ρυθμιστής \latintext{LQR}}

    \section{Περιγραφή}

    \section{Μαθηματική Ανάλυση}

    \section{Τρόπος Επιλογής Πινάκων Ποινής}

    \section{Σχεδίαση Παρατηρητή \latintext{LQE}}

    \section{Σχολιασμός Αποτελεσμάτων}

    \chapter{Επίλογος}

    \begin{appendices}
    \chapter{Παράρτημα Α}

    \end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

It keeps producing the same error no matter what is written at line 43. Even if the whole line is commented out, same error is produced.

Here is the log file:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/xwh5tvxqv69cs03/report.log?dl=0

Comment: When I compile your file with either `xelatex` or `lualatex` I do not get any error. However, I am wondering if adding the `babel` tikzlibary to your document helps.  That is, add `\usetikzlibrary{babel}` under `\usepackage{tikz}`, say, and see if the error persists. (The `quotes` library can have problems with `\usepackage[...]{babel}`.

Comment: Same error is produced.

Comment: How do you compile your document? `xelatex` or `lualatex`?

Comment: I am using texmaker and viewing the file directly as PDF of that helps. I don’t really know the answer.

Comment: Even if I write the whole document from the begining (new file) the same thing happens. I really can't understand why.

Comment: I'd love to help but cannot really reproduce the error. Can you please post the log file such that experts can find out the reason more easily?

Comment: I posted teh log file. I can compile it perfectly when I use Overleaf online editor but same error is produced at both TexMaker and TexStudio, if that helps.

Comment: You have an ancient version of LaTeX: `LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>`. Can you try updating your installation, perhaps this fixes it.

Comment: If you mean to update the texlive distro I have, it says the newest version is installed.

Comment: Line 43 is in report.toc, and the problem is "GenericError" due to hyperref not handling the way you are getting greek letters.

Comment: How can I upgrade the `LaTeX2e 2017` version to the newest one ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The appendices environment seems to break hyperref handling of Greek letters filtered by inputenc when the bookmarks are generated. Can you use the ordinary `\appendix` declaration? Without the `{appendices}` there are warnings about Greek letters not being allowed in the PD1 encoding needed for pdf bookmarks and links, but no hard errors. I haven't tracked the problem all the way to the bottom.

Comment: Now, everything works as it should be. Problem was the `{appendices}` environment.